# Active admin concern dynamic methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have and active admin resource. How i can dynamic extend resource. I try do it like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  include UpdatePriceBlock
  price_blocks_names names: [:last, :actual]

end
```

```
module UpdatePriceBlock
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def price_blocks_names(options = {})
    @price_blocks_names ||= options[:names]
  end

  def self.included(base)
    @price_blocks_names.each do |name|
      base.send :member_action, name,  method: :get do
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now I has an error:

```
undefined method `price_blocks_names' for #<ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible way, I don't know yet how you could keep the names inside the active admin register block. Add the price_blocks_names to your model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  def self.price_bloks_names
    %i(last actual)
  end
end
```

And then place this in `config/initializers/active_admin_update_price_block.rb`

```
module ActiveAdminUpdatePriceBlock
  def self.extended(base)
    base.instance_eval do
      self.controller.resource_class.price_bloks_names.each do |name|
        member_action name, method: :get do
          raise resource.inspect
        end
      end 
    end
  end 
end
```

Now you can extend, but the configuration needs to reside in the model as a class method this way. Haven't found a cleaner way so far.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  extend UpdatePriceBlock
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  controller do
    include UpdatePriceBlock
  end
end
```

What's going on:

Within the `register Order do` block, `self` is a special Active Admin thing:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  puts "What's self here? #{self}"
end
```

=>
`What's self here? #<ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL:0x000000012b948230>`

Within the `controller do` block, it's the controller class (so, pretty much the same as the body of a class definition):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  controller do
    puts "What's self here? #{self}"
    include UpdatePriceBlock
  end
end
```

=> `What's self here? Admin::OrdersController`

Within a `member_action` block, it's an instance of the controller, just like in a regular Rails controller action:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  member_action :action do
    puts "What's self here? #{self}"
  end
end
```

=> `What's self here? #<Admin::OrdersController:0x00000001259e7e80>`